# How can I use a variable in a powershell script run in a shell command?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell

I have a shell script that runs a powershell command (on windows).

```
newPassword="New Value"
powershell -command "sed -i '/password/s/>[^<]*</>$newPassword</' C:/Users/username/.m2/settings.xml"
```

I can echo $newPassword and see the value 'New Value'

I can also run the below script and the password tag gets updated with 'Hello World'

```
powershell -command "sed -i '/password/s/>[^<]*</>Hello World</' C:/Users/username/.m2/settings.xml"
```

However it doesn't update the file by passing in $newPassword. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What shell do you use to run this command line? Why do you need to run PowerShell if you don't run PowerShell cmdlets? You could simply run the command.

Comment: I am not very good with this stuff so maybe I just did something wrong but when I remove the powershell - command stuff it doesn't work. I think it is a windows thing?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just had to add curly braces around my variable

```
powershell -command "sed -i '/password/s/>[^<]*</>{$newPassword}</' C:/Users/username/.m2/settings.xml"
```